# Leaflet custom control not working in IE

Tags: jquery, maps, leaflet

So, Ive got a custom control set to toggle a sidebar. The problem is in IE 10, 9, 8. The control has a mousedown function and it doesnt play well in IE and I cant get 'click' to work either.

```
    // Search Control
    var searchControl = L.Control.extend({
        options: {
            position: 'topleft'

        },

        onAdd: function (map) {
            // create the control container with a particular class name
            var searchcontrol = L.DomUtil.create('div');

            var controlUI = L.DomUtil.create('a', 'global-search2', searchcontrol);
                L.DomEvent
                .on(searchcontrol, 'mousedown', function () {sidebar.toggle(); });

            return searchcontrol;
        }
    });

    map.addControl(new searchControl());


    // Sidebar
    var sidebar = L.control.sidebar('sidebar', {
        closeButton: true,
        position: 'left'
    });
    map.addControl(sidebar);

    setTimeout(function () {
        sidebar.show();
    }, 500);

    map.on('click', function () {
        sidebar.hide();
    })
```

Heres my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/be9PK/1/

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a timing issue with IE. I forked your fiddle here, this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/C5C47/

```
var controlUI = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'global-search2', searchcontrol);
```

I changed your control container from an anchor to a button. This ensures that clicking this element has proper event propagation.